# how to translate javascript getTime() value to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, javascript

I think my brain has just quit on me due to the late hour. Can anyone tell me the best way to translate a javascript getTime() value to a C# DateTime value,

I have an ajax component which sends the JS time value as a parameter to ASP.NET mvc controller which will then return some Json objects.

Thanks for your help.

I do know that the JS time value is the milliseconds passed since Jan 1st 1970.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
new DateTime(1970, 01, 01).AddMilliseconds(jsGetTimeValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. And yes, I did feel quite stupid when I realised the solution. Too many late nights!

Comment: This is not working for `me new Date(1427842800000)` in the chrome console `Wed Apr 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` in `C#` 
`new DateTime(1970, 01, 01).AddMilliseconds(1427842800000);` returns `System.DateTime {31/03/2015 00:00:00}`

Comment: To be accurate, it is `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(jsGetTimeValue)` as js .getTime() considers 1st of Jan 1970 **UTC time** as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this translation in the JavaScript itself, due to a .NET component I didn't have the ability to modify.

To pass the JavaScript value into a C# function which expects `DateTime` I needed to pass the fractional number of days since 12/30/1899 at midnight. I did the conversion with this:

```
var now = new Date();
var days = (now.getTime() / 86400000)-(now.getTimezoneOffset() / 1440)+25569;
```

Then I just pass the `days` into my .NET component.